# Kafka Streams aggregate adder operator issue

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, java-11

Here's my Kafka Streams code:

```
KTable<String, Long> bankTransactionsStream = streamsIn
            .groupByKey()
            .aggregate(
                    ()-> 0L,
                    (aggKey, newValue, aggValue) -> aggValue + newValue,
                    Materialized.<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("test-events-snapshots").withKeySerde(Serdes.String()).
                            withValueSerde(Serdes.String())
            );
```

where I group the stream by the key, then I want to aggregate to add each of the new value of the stream (`newValue`) to the aggregate value (`aggValue`). I'm following the official confluent documentation, but getting two errors highlighted, both of them related to VR data type provided:

1. On the adder `(aggKey, newValue, aggValue) -> aggValue + newValue` ( *Required type: KTable <String,Long> Provided: KTable<String,VR>
   no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Long conforms to String inference variable VR has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: String lower bounds: Long*
2. on the initializer ( `()-> 0L` ): *Required type: KTable <String,Long>, Provided: KTable <String, VR> Incompatible equality constraint: KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]> and StateStore*

I don't get it why does it assume I provide VR type, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The second type here is incorrect; you have a Long

`Materialized.<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>`